Properly discontinuous action of a discrete subgroup of affine group of simply connected Lie group is free if and only if the group is torsion-free?
Reading the book Almost-Bieberbach Groups: Affine and Polynomial Structures, I have two questions.

The first red underline, I can not understand why they are equivalent.
The second red underline, a uniform discrete subgroup of the semiproduct automatically gives a properly discontinuous action?




No, but uniform discrete in this case implies properly discontinuous. See the Lemma in the answer to this post. For 1., a free action is defined how?


Your understanding of proper discontinuity is wrong, it is not the same as a wandering action (although some authors say so by abusing the terminology).

@MoisheKohan You are right. I confused the other meaning of proper discontinuity.

@DietrichBurde I is the usual free action. Any nontrivial group element does not fix any point.

Then it is clear, see this post, because a torsion-free group has no finite subgroup.

I think the hard part will probably be showing that if the action of $\Pi$ on $G$ is free, then $\Pi$ is torsion-free. If $G = \mathbb{R}^n$, then one can prove this by assuming $\Pi$ has a torsion element $\pi$, and showing that the "average of the orbit of $\pi$" is a fixed by $\pi$, hence the action is not free. I'm not sure if a similar thing can be done for any connected and simply connected Lie group $G$ though...

The equivalence 1 is false: if $G$ is simply connected but has nontrivial finite subgroups (e.g., $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{C})$ then let $\Pi$ be such a subgroup: then $\Pi$ acts properly ["properly discontinuously" if you like unnecessary additional words to mean the same] but is not torsion-free. However, the other implication is true. And the equivalence is true when $G$ is contractible.

I removed my opinion and wiki page link for 'properly discontinuous'.

@YCor How contractibility works?

@Link if $G$ is contractible, then $\mathrm{Aut}(G)=\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ is real algebraic, hence has finitely many components. Also, every maximal compact subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is maximal compact in $H=G\ltimes\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, and hence every compact subgroup of $H$, being conjugate to a subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, fixes a point.

@YCor Thanks, but I can’t understand. I need to study more about this. Please tell me one more. Where are torsion elements used in your comment?

If the group is not torsion-free, it has a nontrivial finite subgroup, which is a compact subgroup, which by the argument of my comment fixes a point in $G$.

Okay. I will try to understand your arguments now.
